# Does the internet speed affect other processes in Ubuntu (18.04)?

Tags: networking, 18.04, internet

This question may be silly, but I'd like to ask about it, since I'm still a beginner when it comes to how the OS works.

I moved to a new house where the internet speed is quite slow. So, naturally, accessing the internet from my computer takes more time than before.

Interestingly, the other processes or operations have also become slower ever since I came to this house (where the internet is slow).

For example, saving a file on a text editor (e.g. Sublime Text) used to be done as soon as I hit the save button.

However, now it takes 1-2 seconds for my computer to save a file.
[image]

Likewise, even a simple task, such as opening a file, is slower than before.

Here is what `htop` shows.
[image]
As you can see, it's not running out of memory. nor the CPUs are too busy.

The only culprit I can think of is the internet, because this computer used to work fine when the internet was fast.

So, does the internet possibly affect the entire computer's performance?

Any advice will be appreciated.
(This computer is running on Ubuntu 18.04)

***PS***

Here is what `iotop` shows. I don't believe that there are too many I/O processes... but how do you think about this result?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Time that used for save file depends on your hard drive speed. Please, use `sudo iotop` command for clarify your problem. Also, you can try any other editor to make compare test.

By the other hand, if you are using network file system, of course, saving file depends on your internet connection speed.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion! It doesn't seem that there are too many I/O processes (I updated the original question. You'll see the result of `iotop`). Also, when I run `showmount`, the terminal says that "clnt_create: RPC: Program not registered". So, I suppose that my computer isn't using network file system (I got this idea from here ... https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSNY3_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/t0007072.html)

Comment: Have you tried to use another editor?

Comment: Seems your hard drive is almost not used. In this case disk IO can not be the reason of slowing down.

Comment: Is "Usage history" option is enabled? You can find this option at Settings -> Privacy. I recommend to turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the red bars your cpu's spend a lot of time in the kernel which means a lot of io (or waiting a lot on io). On desktop systems this is most often caused by waiting on the disk (for firewalls/routers it would be network related).

As you have moved I would check the sata cable, disconnect and reconnect each end. A bad sata connection will not directly cause total failure because sata has error detection and it recovers be re transmitting the data. But if it has to re transmit a lot things will get slow.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I checked and re-connected sata cables, but doing so didn't make a noticeable change. Still, I really appreciate your advice!